# Draw Text with a border and background for a NSTableView cell

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstableview

I have a cell-based tableview and I want to display some sort of tags within this tableview, preferably without having to use a view-based tableview.

Is there an elegant way to achieve something like the example here (HTML), ideally with a background-color as well.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stick with a cell-based table view, you can subclass `NSCell` and override:

```
- (void)drawWithFrame:(NSRect)cellFrame inView:(NSView*)controlView
{
    NSRect insetRect = NSInsetRect(cellFrame, 2.0, 2.0);
    NSBezierPath* path = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:insetRect xRadius:3.0 yRadius:3.0];
    [path stroke];
    [[NSColor whiteColor] setFill];
    [path fill];
    [[NSColor brownColor] setStroke];
    [path stroke];
    NSMutableAttributedString* content = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"DUPLICATE"];
    NSFontManager* fontManager = [NSFontManager sharedFontManager];
    NSFont* font = [fontManager fontWithFamily:@"Verdana"
                                              traits:NSBoldFontMask
                                              weight:0
                                                size:13.0];
    NSDictionary* attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName:font,
                                 NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[NSColor brownColor]};
    [content setAttributes:attributes range:NSMakeRange(0, [content length])];
    [content setAlignment:NSCenterTextAlignment range:NSMakeRange(0, [content length])];
    [content drawInRect:cellFrame];
}
```

The above code generates a cell that vaguely resembles your button (you'll have to tweak fonts, colours, line-styles etc. yourself):

[image]

I also adjusted the row height in the table view delegate by providing:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView heightOfRow:(NSInteger)row
{
    return 24.0;
}
```

Comment: Can you know at "draw-time" what size the cell will have and adjust the size of the border?

Comment: The frame rectangle of the cell gets passed in via cellFrame. If you want to measure your text, you can use NSAttributedString's boundingRectWithSize:options: