# Draw the border around particular part of text in label

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have attached a screen shot of label should show following contents.
Time stamp text appended by two images and again one text having white border.
    I've append images to label by using NSTextAttachment then i'm appending the text that has to show either at last or in between two images depends on condition. With one more label I can achieve this easily if text comes every time at the end but it won't.I saw so many tutorials to create the border for complete text of label.Is there any way to create border only for particular part of label text.[image]

Comment: That's not easy. `NSAttributedString` doesn't have anything build for this, and so you may have to play with CoreText. Best solution? Have image pre-built, for the "PG-n", draw yourself the image and then you can use `NSTextAttachment`, use a specific font (or create one) that have this "PG-13" considering it as a "symbol"/char with the border...

Comment: Hi Larme, You mean to say create border and text as image and append to label. Could you explain briefly.

Comment: Some lead/idea: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23236703/draw-text-with-a-border-and-background-for-a-nstableview-cell

Comment: @manideep let me know if my answer solves your issue

Answer (score 9):

You need to make an image with your needed text and attach to the text as `NSTextAttachment` here is the implementation for that

**Objective-C Version**
**You can make your PG image like this**

```
@implementation ImageHelper

+(UIImage*)imageForText:(NSString*)text{
        UILabel * lblBadge = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,16,16)];
        [lblBadge setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
        [lblBadge setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByClipping];
        [lblBadge setTextColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
        [lblBadge.layer setCornerRadius:2.0f];
        [lblBadge.layer setBorderWidth:1];
        [lblBadge setText:text];
        [lblBadge sizeToFit];
        [lblBadge setBounds:CGRectMake(0,0,lblBadge.bounds.size.width + 4,lblBadge.bounds.size.height)];

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(lblBadge.bounds.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
        [lblBadge.layer setAllowsEdgeAntialiasing:YES];
        [lblBadge.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
        UIImage * img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        return img;
}

@end
```

**example of Use**

```
NSMutableAttributedString * normalNameString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:@"testing "];

NSTextAttachment * attachment = [[NSTextAttachment alloc] init];
attachment.image = [ImageHelper imageForText:@"PG-13"];
attachment.bounds = CGRectMake(0, -6, attachment.image.size.width, attachment.image.size.height);
[normalNameString appendAttributedString:[NSAttributedString attributedStringWithAttachment:attachment]];

self.lblText.attributedText = normalNameString;
```

**Swift Version**

**You can make your PG image like this**

```
class imageHelper{
    static func pgImage(textValue:String) ->UIImage{
        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 15, height: 16))
        label.lineBreakMode = .byClipping
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.textColor = UIColor.darkGray
        label.layer.borderColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
        label.layer.borderWidth = 1
        label.layer.cornerRadius = 2
        label.text = textValue
        label.sizeToFit()
        label.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: label.bounds.size.width + 4, height: label.bounds.size.height)

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(label.bounds.size, false, UIScreen.main.scale)
        label.layer.allowsEdgeAntialiasing = true
        label.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)

        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image!
    }
}
```

**example of Use**

```
        let normalNameString = NSMutableAttributedString.init(string: "testing ")

        let attachment = NSTextAttachment()
        attachment.image = imageHelper.pgImage(textValue: "PG-13")
        attachment.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: -6, width: (attachment.image?.size.width)!, height: (attachment.image?.size.height)!)
        normalNameString.append(NSAttributedString(attachment: attachment))

        self.lblText.attributedText = normalNameString
```

**RESULT**

[image]

Comment: how to decrease the font size and then in an image form?Actually when i do that the font size looks very big so any solution @Reinier Melian

Comment: @Aashi you need to change the font size in `imageForText` method something like `[lblBadge setFont: YourFont];`

Comment: If I want to give space between testing and PG-13, what I need to do @ReinierMelian. Thanks in advance.